# how to prevent losing remote changes when saving file locally after a git pull

Tags: git, sftp, textmate, cyberduck

I use textmate and cyberduck to edit css files on a remote server. others regularly edit the same files. we all use git for version control.
sometimes I have a file open in textmate and I do a git pull which pulls that file with someone elses changes then I save my local changes to the file in textmate and upload it and I end up losing the other persons changes.
I know I can prevent this by closing all textmate windows before doing a git pull, but Im wondering what is a better way to prevent this from happening.
thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `textmate` to edit files.

Switch to an editor like **[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)** that warns you if an open file is edited by some other software.